# Value of $t$ in Fuzzy Exractor

Tags: encryption, randomness, information-theory, coding-theory

Is there a defined method to choose value of $t$ when using fuzzy extractor to reconcile two close secrets?

I did try with multiple values ranging from 5 to close to half of the sequence.
I understand it statistically depends on chance of error, difference between close sets.

Comment: Could you add some more background about what particular extractor you're using, please? I have no clue what $t$ is. :)

Comment: I am using https://www.cs.bu.edu/~reyzin/fuzzy.html

Comment: I'm not an academic, so their paper is difficult to understand. I am a pragmatist however. I don't see any testing.  I expected to see something like Lena with and without her hat outputting the same value, or at least a match %age  Does their theory actually work?

Comment: Yes this works where I use $t$ empirically. Do you know any other fuzzy extractor which works well to extract common secret from two close inputs?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did find that it depends on maximum number of mismatch between sets.